# Lost my custom data files for OWASP ZAP (Forced Browse) - where do I find the data in ZAP?

Tags: owasp

The tool used to be called dirbuster. I imported my own lists then lost the source files. I can't export the wordlists from ZAP. How can I find the data in ZAP so that I can recreate the source files?

Answer (score 1):

ZAP stores the custome forced browse files you upload in a directory called 'dirbuster' under the default directory. The default directory depends on the OS - eg its ~/.ZAP on linux - for full details see this FAQ: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQconfig

Comment: Thanks - came here after testing why my updated dictionary wasn't working...turns out that when uploading reference file it's cloned into dirbuster dir.

Unfortunately, I don't see a way to remove/refresh the file content from the GUI, since when attempting to overwrite the file the instruction is aborted with something like "file already exists".

Is there a better way to handle this? I'm storing custom (optimized) dictionaries on my personal cloud (otherwise I'd just edit file directly in /dirbuster) and hate having to manually refresh as I build it up...